# efficient hash function for uris

Tags: hash, collision

i am looking for a hash function to build a (global) fixed size id for 
strings, most of them URIs.

it should be:

- fast
- low chance of collision
- ~ 64bit
- exploiting the structure of an uri if that is possible?

would http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/ be a good choice or is there anything better suited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320). As far as cryptography is concerned, it is "broken", but since you do not have any security concern (you want a 64-bit output size, which is too small to yield any decent security against collisions), that should not be a problem. MD4 yields a 128-bit value, which you just have to truncate to the size you wish.

Cryptographic hash functions are designed for resilience to explicit attempts at building collisions. Conceivably, one can build a faster function by relaxing that condition (it is easier to beat random collisions than a determinate attacker). There are a few such functions, e.g. MurmurHash. *However* it may take a quite specific setup to actually notice the speed difference. With my home PC (a 2.4 GHz Core2), I can hash about 10 millions of short strings per second with MD4, using a single CPU core (I have four cores). For MurmurHash to be faster than MD4 in a non-negligible way, it would have to be used in a context involving at least one million hash invocations per second. That does not happen very often...

Comment: i think md4 should be ok. i may even take more bits.

but still i wonder if it would be possible and make sense to optimize a hash function for URIs. the idea would be that ie the top tld and maybe even the domain are more common than the chars at the end.

Comment: I've actually benchmarked MurmurHash against SHA-1, so I can assure you that the difference is quite significant in practice. It's especially painful for many short strings, as SHA-1 has a huge setup cost, but even with long strings intermixed with I/O, the difference adds up quickly.

Answer (score -1):

I'd wait a little longer for MurmurHash3 to be finalized, then use that. The 128-bit version should give you adequate collision protection against the birthday paradox.